# How to merge data frames

Tags: dataframe, merge, data-transform

Hi I'm a beginner with R and trying to merge two data frames under specific conditions.

I have a data frame called 'carabidae_data'. It has a column 'DATE' with dates, many of the same date values repeated a few times.

I have a second data frame called 'temp_data'. It has a column 'sampling_date' with dates, a column temp_maxima, temp_minima and mean_temp, each with temperature values that correspond to the dates in 'sampling_date', which are the same dates as in 'DATE'.

I want to add to 'carabidae_data' 3 new columns: temp_maxima, temp_minima and mean_temp with the temperatures that correspond to the correct date.

Basically the end product should be a new data frame with the dates and corresponding temperature values as well as the other data that was in carabidae_data before.

Thank you:)